# Does a cyclist in front of two also profits from the slipstream the second cyclists profits from?

Tags: aerodynamics

It is well known when two cyclists are driving together, one in front, one on the back, that the second cyclist profits from the slipstream provided by the man (or woman) in front. Does the first cyclist also profit from the situation? I can imagine that the turbulence (the slipstream) behind the first cyclist somehow "backfires" (or gives feedback) to the wind stream passing the man on top.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - The primary reason for the slipstream is the low pressure region the first guy creates. He himself has regular atomspheric pressure in front and low pressure behind so the air is trying to slow him down. He cannot profit from his own slipstream.

Comment: @user1936752 No he can't, but he can profit from a modified flow, meaning that if the second rider increases the range over which air flows "laminar" over both riders, decreasing the overall turbulent region of rider one, it can actually decrease drag on rider one as well. I am not sure if this takes place in cycling but it sure does in car racing with a more sophisticated aerodynamics. I consider this part of the success of tandem draft in NASCAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is yes.
See [CFD simulations of the aerodynamic drag of two drafting cyclists](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwiKg_iGza3UAhVHOxQKHfrFAXwQFgg4MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbanphysics.net%2F2013_CAF_BB_TD_EK_JC_PH__Preprint.pdf&usg=AFQjCNExj5Vz4E7Ix7XU_DRUhetcifOG5Q&sig2=_3j-M2Q-e8Fqtu6Jt4EhDA)
.

Comment: I think that this is the best proof you can get! Trying to calculate it will be very complicated!

Comment: @descheleschilder Indeed, definitively not a pencil and paper job.